# Version of Paley-Wiener theorem for Fourier transform on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is a continuous function of  moderate decay on $\mathbb{R}$. Show that $f$ has an analytic extension to $\mathbb{C}$ which satisfies $ |f(z)|\leq ce^{a|z|^p}$ for some $c,a>0, p\in (0,1)$, and all $z\in \mathbb{C}$ , if and only if $\hat{f}(t)\equiv0$ and hence $f(z)\equiv 0$.

This is a version of Paley- Wiener type of Theorem for the Fourier transform on $\mathbb{R}$.

Since I am thinking to apply $e^{a|z|^p} \leq e^{\epsilon |z|^1}$ for large $|z|$. From the paley-Wiener theorem , we can say $\hat{f}(z)$ has a support on some closed interval. But , how do I argue ,$\hat{f}(t)$  is identically zero.

I am struggling with this problem for long time.
Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "moderate decay"?

Comment: This is the condition on the function $f$. That is $f(x)\leq \frac{A}{1+x^2}$ for some positive $A$.

Comment: Your idea works because the classical PW theorem gives that $\widehat{f}$ is supported by $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$.

Comment: Thanks , I am gonna try this idea and see how this works

Comment: Santosh, this is also your homework question. Your solutions of homework problems are supposed to be your own work. Please remove all the homework questions from the site.

Comment: Okay professor, I am going to  stop using this immediately and delete all the problems that I asked in this blog.